# Invalid bind expression type of Task for column of type Id

Tags: list, taskrelation

I tried to get all related tasks from the selected contact, but salesforce don't like my code.
If I try to save I get the error: Invalid bind expression type of Task for column of type Id

What I'm doing wrong?

```
          List<Taskrelation> RelatedTasks = [select taskId from taskrelation where relationid =: currentRecordId];
            for (task rt : RelatedTasks) {
                for(Task a: [select Id, Subject, CreatedDate, Createdby.Name, Owner.Name, RecordType.Name, Status, Who.Name, Who.Id, What.Name from Task where Id =:rt]) { 
                    wrapperList.add(new Wrapper(a, 'task'));
                } 
            }
```

Comment: `TaskRelation` is a different object than `Task` -- you can't compare their Ids.  Also you have a `SELECT` statement inside the outer for loop so you are going to have problems with governor limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** coming to the issue

`[select Id, Subject, CreatedDate, Createdby.Name, Owner.Name, RecordType.Name, Status, Who.Name, Who.Id, What.Name from Task where Id =:rt]`

Here `rt` is `sObject` , whereas it should be `Id`

`[select Id, Subject, CreatedDate, Createdby.Name, Owner.Name, RecordType.Name, Status, Who.Name, Who.Id, What.Name from Task where Id =:rt.Id]`

**Secondly**, you should always avoid SOQL in for loop. You can move this query outside loop and pass `relatedTaskIds`. And insert data to `relatedTaskIds` after looping through `RelatedTasks` for eg:

```
for(Task a: [select Id, Subject, CreatedDate, Createdby.Name, Owner.Name, RecordType.Name, Status, Who.Name, Who.Id, What.Name from Task where Id In :relatedTaskIds]) {
    wrapperList.add(new Wrapper(a, 'task'));
}
```

Comment: Just want to add to this that you can use `Id =: rt` where rt is sObject or list of sObjects, in this case it will use the Ids of those sObjects. That is the reason why it is throwing error on  Invalid bind. On left side you have Task Id and ont the right side you have RelatedTask Id.

Comment: @Nagendra, I tried to use your second way, but I get also an error: Invalid bind expression type of TaskRelation for Id field of SObject Task  |||         List<Taskrelation> RelatedTaskIds = [select taskId from taskrelation where relationid =: currentRecordId];                
for(Task a: [select Id, Subject, CreatedDate, Createdby.Name, Owner.Name, RecordType.Name, Status, Who.Name, Who.Id, What.Name from Task where Id In :RelatedTaskIds]) {
    wrapperList.add(new Wrapper(a, 'task'));
}